# is it possible to share constraint cross-blocks?

Tags: python, pyomo

I have a parent block (Block0) containing 3 sub-blocks:

1. Block1 and Block2 formulate the same problem A, but with slightly different set of indexes
2. Block3 formulates another problem B, which uses quadratic constraints
3. Block1 and Block2 make use of decision variables within Block3 (which are constrained by such quadratic constraint) to determine the solution of problem A

The implementation logic is something along these lines:

```py
block0 = pyo.ConcreteModel("Block0")

block3 = prepare_problemB_model(data3)
block0.add_component("Block3", block3)


block1 = prepare_problemA_model(data1, block3.component_objects(pyo.Var))
block2 = prepare_problemA_model(data2, block3.component_objects(pyo.Var))

block0.add_component("Block1", block1)
block0.add_component("Block2", block2)

block0.obj = pyo.Objective(expr=block1.obj + block2.obj + block3.obj)
```

I can solve block0 if the decision variables within Block3 (which are shared with Block1 and Block2) are fixed to a constant value. Otherwise I get the following error:

```
ERROR: Model contains an expression (*CONSTRAINT-NAME*)
    that contains a variable (*VAR-NAME*) that is not attached to an active
    block on the submodel being written
```

Do you have any ideas? is a straightforward way to copy Block3's model into Block1 and Block2?

I'm using pyomo 6.5.0 with gurobi solver

Thanks

Comment: You likely need to add any common elements between the blocks to your "base block"

Comment: I tried integrating Block3 into Block0 (let's call it Block03), but I get the same error

Comment: I don't use separate blocks for much, but willing to take a look.  Can you update your post to include a reduced size example of what you are trying to do that produces the error?  (a minimal reproducible example gets the best responses on this site)  https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: I'm betting $5 that the eventual answer is that things used within a block need to be defined in the block (no inheritance)...  we shall see if someone who is "block savvy" chimes in.  There are probably alternate approaches here.  It sounds like you are doing some kind of 2-stage solve using different models

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is to upgrade to Pyomo 6.6.1.

The slightly longer explanation is that the original LP writer had a step where it “pre-collected” model variables by walking the model (block tree that the writer was handed) before collecting the active constraints. This was done to make certain operations more efficient. The error you are seeing was raised when a constraint referenced an unfixed variable that was not found by that initial collection. Pyomo removed this restriction in 6.5 for the NL writer and in 6.6 for the LP writer (the Baron and GAMS interfaces still have it, and will hopefully be relaxed in 6.7).

Comment: My gosh, what a waste of time....upgrading pyomo solved the issue, thanks